# Sanitize user input for inclusion in href attribute?

Tags: python, django, url, escaping

I would like to accept a user inputted url and display it in the `href` attribute part of the link tag. ie.

```
<a href="%(user_input)s">My link name</a>
```

But I would like to make sure that it doesn't have any malicious content as far as inject script tags and the like. What is the best approach to sanitizing the `user_input` part?

From what I can tell:

- `django.utils.html.escape` would escape `&`'s which is bad.
- `django.utils.http.urlquote` and `django.utils.http.urlquote_plus` would escape the `:` part of `http://` amoungst other things which seems bad.

Perhaps the best approach is `urlquote_plus` with some safe characters specified?

Comment: What is the nature of the user input?  Normally, it would be best to constrain what the user can enter to a simple language (something like "an integer" or "a single word") and not just have user input be any possible string.   If it has to be an arbitrary string, can you please explain why you'd want to turn a user's string into part of a link like this?   Is it just like an anchor reference?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits - Thanks for the response. It is from part of a site where users can add their own links which should be related to the place being described on the page. I'm keen to make sure it isn't an avenue for attack though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over thinking the problem. It turns out that using `django.utils.html.escape` is fine as it results in HTML that has link tags with an `href` attributes which might have `&amp;` in them instead of `&` but the browser handles this fine.

I thought I needed to find a way to have `&` in there as urls don't have `&amp;` in them.

My final code is:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import escape

....

output = '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' \
   % (escape(entry['url']), escape(self.link_display(entry)))

return mark_safe(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the template tag: safe.

Let's say that your post context variable is:

`user_input = some_valid_url`

Grab user_input, and add the html to make it a link and reinsert it when saving the post. So the saved post is:

`link_text = <a href=user_input>Link</a>`

And then use safe in your html template:

`{{ link_text|safe }}`

Here is the documentation link for safe template tags:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does `safe` actually do any escaping or simply mark the contents as safe so that Django doesn't escape them?